# Dublicate characters in PaddleOCR

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, ocr, text-recognition, paddleocr

I am trying to detect number plate of vehicles using paddleOCR. In the output, some characters are being repeated. For example:

Orignal Number: HP829
PaddleOCR Output: HHP8229

Orignal Number: PB6279
PaddleOCR Output: PB662799

I am using base PaddleOCR model and have not trained it. But when i upload the same number plate image to paddleOCR site, I get the correct results.

Thanks